# How do I locate email threads using Microsoft Graph SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I want send an email using Microsoft Graph SDK.  Then, when the recipient replies to the email, I want to associate the reply to the sent message.

So I've sent a message using

```
GraphClient.Users[userId].SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

Then had the user reply to it.  When I read both the sent and received messages back via

```
GraphClient.Users[userId].MailFolders[{folderName}].Messages...;
```

I discovered that the `ConversationId` property on both were the same.  I have the following questions:

1. Is `ConversationId` the mechanism by which I associate emails?
2. When I execute `GraphClient.Users[userId].SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync()`, is there a way to get back the `ConversationId` of the message that was just sent?
3. I don't want to poll, so is there a way to hook into Azure where it notifies me when an email has been received for a certain user?
4. If #3 is a "yes", can I hook into it so that it only notifies me for a reply arrived for a specific `ConversationId`?

Answer (score 2):

1. ConversationId can be used to associate all the emails that belong to a particular email thread. If you want to know if a particular email was a response to an another email within the thread then use the In-Reply-to header. You can either get the In-Reply-To header by requesting the InternetHeaders https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/internetmessageheader?view=graph-rest-1.0 (this will return all the headers) or you can request the extended property to just get that one property eg

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@domain.com')/MailFolders('Inbox')/messages/?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject,IsRead,inferenceClassification,InternetMessageId,parentFolderId,hasAttachments,webLink&$Top=10&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20'String%200x1042'))
```

2. Sends are always asynchronous in Exchange (which is what the Graph is using) so they return Void (or accepted in graph). So if you want the conversationId you will require another request to find the SentMessage and extract it from there. One way to do this is you can set the InternetMessageId on the Message your sending or create your own extended property eg these options are discussed https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3766

3,4 Subscription Webhooks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0 are what would work well for this but the ability to create a Filter (eg on the coversationId or In-reply-To) is still in the backlog (AFAIK) https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/19081306-add-select-and-filter-to-webhook-resource-subs

Comment: Yesterday, the ConversationId was matching between sent and replied messages.  But today it isn't. Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: I also looked into the Reply-To headers of the response message, but didn't see anything useful there.  https://i.imgur.com/RWMntwK.png